# Python: Can I put multiple variables into a URL for an API to a database?

Tags: python, url

I'm trying to use Python to access a database via an API. The first part of my code works just fine. So this Python snippet...

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://api.sportradar.us/ncaafb-p1/2016/REG/schedule.json?
api_key=5tpxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

response = requests.get(url)
json_data = response.json()

for games in json_data['weeks'][0]['games']:
    id = games.get('id')
    hid = games.get('home')
    vid = games.get('away')
    print("hometeam ",hid, " visitor ",vid, " game id ",id)
```

...produces this output:

```
hometeam  CAL  visitor  HAW  game id  1c4ee96d-3f08-43e1-8357-3bc2ee8bcaf8
hometeam  NDS  visitor  CCH  game id  6f5121d1-d813-4ba3-bdf3-badf6412fa4f
hometeam  WAG  visitor  SAC  game id  9a39c485-9930-4f70-8a16-59d9bc5e7822
hometeam  MIZST  visitor  SWC  game id  196a7570-18d9-41ae-baa6-57ad9a3abce0
.......
```

What I'm trying to do now is take the variables `hid` and `vid` and insert them as variables into a second URL and make another call to the database.

```
curl = '"http://api.sportradar.us/ncaafb-p1/2016/REG/1/{the vid variable}/{the hid variable}/boxscore.json?api_key=5tpxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
cresponse = requests.get(curl)
x = cresponse.json()
print(x)
```

Is this just a syntax issue? I tried to do it this way...

```
curl = '"http://api.sportradar.us/ncaafb-p1/2016/REG/1/{s}/{s}/boxscore.json?api_key=5tpxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".format(vid, hid)'
```

and I've tried this:

```
curl = '"http://api.sportradar.us/ncaafb-p1/2016/REG/1/%s/%s/boxscore.json?api_key=5tpxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"%(vid, hid)'
```

And this:

```
curl = '"http://api.sportradar.us/ncaafb-p1/2016/REG/1/%s/%s/boxscore.json?s=%s.ns&vid=%s&hid=%sapi_key=5tpxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"%(ticker, vid, hid)
```

But I'm still getting various error messages. Any thoughts on how to do this correctly (given that `hid` and `vid` are multi-letter combinations like CAL and HAW)?

Comment: any log error we can see?

Comment: The placement, positions, and types of quotes (single vs. double) seem to be causing the issue, move the `.format(vid, hid)` *outside* (after) the closing quotes, and usually triple-quoting long strings makes long quotes easier: `curl = """http://api.sportradar.us/ncaafb-p1/2016/REG/1/{the_vid_variable}/{the_hid_variable}/boxscore.json?api_key=5tpxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""".format(the_vid_variable=vid, the_hid_variable=hid)`